# Is there any documentation about Intellij/Android Studio's codestyle xml?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, documentation

I'm looking for something that will explain what each of the things mean and are supposed to do.  For example, in the codestyle that we are using we include this:

```
<option name="JD_ADD_BLANK_AFTER_DESCRIPTION" value="false" />
```

I'm guessing that means something about adding a blank line after a description in JavaDoc, but whether I set the value to true or to false, I don't notice any changes in the way it autoformats our code/JavaDoc.

If this isn't the right StackExchange place to ask this question, let me know and I'll ask elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation for the XML, because it's not intended to be viewed or edited by users. However, all the options controlled by the XML file are documented in the [IntelliJ IDEA online help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html). Also, the code style settings dialog highlights the changes which are applied to the code as you change each setting.

The correspondence between XML tag names and UI text can be inferred from the source code, for example from [this class](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/JavaLanguageCodeStyleSettingsProvider.java).